# Recommended way for variable scoping

Tags: r, scope

In C and variants, when you have something like this:

```
{
  tmp1 <- 5
  tmp2 <- 2
  print(tmp1 + tmp2)
}
```

a 7 will be printed, but the `tmp1` and `tmp2` variables will be removed from stack once the scope `}` ends. I sometimes want similar functionality in R so that I do not have to clean up (many) temporary variables after some point in time.

One way to make this work in R is like this:

```
(function(){
  tmp1 <- 5
  tmp2 <- 2
  print(tmp1 + tmp2)
})()
```

Now that seems a bit hackish -- or it may be just me.

**Are there any better or more concise (i.e. more readable) ways to do this in R?**

Comment: In addition to `local()`, you could also use `with()` with a dummy variable - `with(1, { tmp1 <- 5; tmp2 <- 2; print(tmp1 + tmp2) })`.  It also creates a local environment.

Comment: @nicola, I have been long time looking for a way to do variable scoping in R and never found the old duplicate of this question which is indeed 99% the same. So I'll leave this one as an alternative for searches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to use `local` in base R for that purpose:

```
local({
  tmp1 <- 5
  tmp2 <- 2
  print(tmp1 + tmp2)
})
```

So any variable created within the scope of `local` will vanish as soon as the scope is left.

From `?local`:

> `local` evaluates an expression in a local environment.

See `?local` for more details.

---

Additionally, `with` (suggested by @Rich Scriven in the comments) also in base R can be used where `1` is just a dummy data:

```
with(1, {
    tmp1 <- 5
    tmp2 <- 2
    print(tmp1 + tmp2)
})
```

From `?with`:

> `with` is a generic function that evaluates expr in a local environment constructed from data.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! -- I'll wait a bit to accept as an answer, although this seems as a very clean R-way to simulate variable scoping.

Answer (score 0):

Within the main code body the variables are global. However, as you found yourself their scope is local within functions:

```
addme <- function(){
    tmp1 <- 5;
    tmp2 <- 2;
    return (tmp1+tmp2)
}
```

then call calling `addme()` will return the sum, but the variable remain inaccessible outside

```
> addme()
[1] 7
> tmp1
Error: object 'tmp1' not found
```

Comment: That would still leave me with a function definition I have to remove...

Comment: true. Anyway, I learned something about the `with()` function ;)